# Pagination on Single-Entry view in ExpressionEngine

Tags: pagination, expressionengine

I am building a website with ExpressionEngine as the CMS. There is a "Work" section that displays all the projects, and a detail view that shows each project individually. It is at this point, on the single-entry view that I would like to have "prev" and "next" pagination. In my tests I have made it work when the URL is "somedomain.com/index.php/work/detail/" but it does not work when the specific entry is part of the URL: "somedomain.com/index.php/work/detail/some_project/"

I've tried putting the pagination code outside of the {exp:weblog:entries} tag as well as within it, but to no avail. This is what my pagination code looks like:

```
{paginate}
    <ul>
        {if previous_page}
        <li><a href="{auto_path}">< previous</a></li>
        {/if}

        {if next_page}
        <li><a href="{auto_path}">next ></a></li>
        {/if}
    </ul>
{/paginate}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using pagination for lists of entries, what you need is the next / previous entry tags:

```
http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/entry_linking.html
```

Comment: I'm using the EE 1.6.9 Core version. It does not seem to have the Channel Module, is it only available for paid versions? This is a client site, so they are planning on purchasing anyway. Hopefully that will solve my problem! Thanks!

Comment: they just renamed the weblog module as the channel module

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I'm not sure what the issue is here, as I've never used the `{pagination}` tag in that way. After checking out [the docs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/pagination_page.html), I see that the example code for prev/next links inside of the `{pagination}` tag is wrapped inside of an `{exp:comment:entries}` loop instead of the normal `{exp:channel:entries}` loop.

The docs aren't very clear about the scope of this particular feature of the `{pagination}` tag. You might want to double check that, in your `{exp:channel:entries}` loop, you haven't included pagination as a value in the `disable` parameter.

You could also check out the page in EE's user guide about [Next/Prev Linking](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/entry_linking.html), which details the use of `{exp:channel:next_entry}` and `{exp:channel:prev_entry}` tags in place of the `{pagination}` tag that you've been using. I've used these tags without a hitch, so I definitely recommend trying them if you can't get your method to work.

Best of luck!